# Python regex split multiline inclusive of pattern

Tags: python, regex, include, split, multiline

I'm receiving data similar to this format in python

```
garbage
=== Season 1 ===
season 1 data
more season 1 data
=== Season 2 ===
season 2 data
```

with newlines, but the data between the '=== Season x ===' isn't defined (it's coming from Wikipedia's API if you know it).

Anyway, I'm trying to break it up using regex's, but can't seem to get it right. I try

```
p = re.compile('(===\sSeason.*)'
print p.split(data)
```

and get

```
['garbarge\n', '=== Season 1 ===', '\nseason 1 data\nmore season 1 data\n\n', '=== Season 2 ===', '\nseason 2 data\n']
```

but what I'm looking for is:

```
['garbarge\n', '=== Season 1 ===\nseason 1 data\nmore season 1 data\n\n', '=== Season 2 ===\nseason 2 data\n']
```

with each pattern including the text up until the next pattern, newlines and all. I've tried combinations of re.MULTILINE, re.DOTALL, I can't seem to get it right. Any help?

Comment: I wouldn't use regular expressions for this. After you find a line starting with '=== Season', simply group the data until you find a new line with '=== Season'. Anything that comes before the first '=== Season' is, apparently, garbage and, as such, you discard it.

Comment: Yeah, my original solution used a similar regex and recursively called re.search() to find the starting index of each pattern to break up the data via substring, but I was hoping to use regex's to do that for me.

Comment: But since you will have to step through the lines of unknown data in between each season section anyways, you might as well just loop over each line and create a new "season" grouping when you hit the season delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward way to do this is to step through the content line by line:

```
season = ''
for line in data.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('=== Season'):
        season = line
    elif season:
        do something
```

Comment: This is basically what my original solution was - I thought I could make it more elegant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why that isn't working exactly, but this seems to work for me:

```
>>> data = """
garbage
=== Season 1 ===
season 1 data
more season 1 data
=== Season 2 ===
season 2 data
"""
>>> re.split('^===\sSeason\s\d+\s===$',data,0,re.MULTILINE)
['\ngarbage\n', '\nseason 1 data\nmore season 1 data\n', '\nseason 2 data\n']
```

Oh..that's not quite what you want is it? But `split` strips out the thing you're splitting on; if you wanted to keep it in, then you're not using the right tool for the job.

Here's another solution that's a bit more complex, it filters out the "garbage" but keeps the season info in:

```
>>> re.findall('=== Season \d+ ===.*?(?=^===|\Z)',data,re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
['=== Season 1 ===\nseason 1 data\nmore season 1 data\n', '=== Season 2 ===\nseason 2 data\n']
```

Comment: Oh..that's not quite what you want is it? But `split` strips out the thing you're splitting on; if you wanted to keep it in, then you're not using the right tool for the job.

Comment: That's what I get without using the grouping () yes. I was hoping to get the === Season === tag inclusive of the data it broke it down to, so index 2 for instance, would be
'=== Season 2 ===\nseason 2 data\n'

Comment: Oooo the lookahead is nice - I failed at trying to write that here too. Thanks Mark (changed my username. user1902788 was too easy to remember). :)

Comment: I find the magic constant `0` in `re.split('^===\sSeason\s\d+\s===$',data,0,re.MULTILINE)` to be confusing. Had to read the docs to figure it out. `maxsplit=0` is the default anyway. It seems that you are including it because it is positional, as opposed to having: `re.split('^===\sSeason\s\d+\s===$',data,flags=re.MULTILINE)`